# Why is there visible liquid (possibly water) on matches when they're burning?

Tags: oxidation-state

I was just burning a normal standard match and I observed visible liquid running down the wooden shaft as the fire burns and consumes it, what could explain such phenomenon ? could it be that the wood "sweats" when it's burning ?

Comment: In most cases this is just [molten] paraffin which the match stick is impregnated with. Paraffin is used to stabilize and prolong burning.

Comment: Wood _does_ sweat in certain circumstances, but it has to be wet in the first place, which the match wood is definitely not. No, this is just molten wax coating, like **andselisk** said.

Comment: oh thank you. I thought somehow the little water inside the wooden components is coming out to the surface and vaporizing as it's burning so for a split second it's visible.

Comment: If the liquid on the match sizzles like a drop of water on a stove, I'm prepared to bet it is indeed water. ;-)

Comment: Water surely leaves burning wood and recondense.